# Asynchronous communication issue

Tags: angular2-services

Hi all I have a big issue in Angular2 that is Asynchronous Communication issue. In the following code buffer is appending with values before response has arrived to the component.ts and i am using promises. Please go through the following code. Big Thanks for help

```
/* component.ts */
ngOnInit() {
  let buffer = '';
  const tempModel = this.appMenuService.getMenusForUser();
  tempModel.then(res => {
             this.modelData = JSON.parse( res.toString() ); 
             setTimeout(() => {}, 10000 );
            console.log(this.modelData);

        });
  buffer = buffer + " \n";
                buffer = buffer + "{ \n  label: 'Institutions In OMS' , icon:'fa fa-fw fa-institution', onOpenIcon:'fa fa-fw fa-institution', \n";
                buffer = buffer + "items:[ \n";
                for(let i = 0; i < this.modelData.length - 1; i++) {
                 buffer = buffer + "label: this.translate.instant('"+this.modelData[i]+"'"+", icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-bell-o', routerLink: ['/"+this.modelData[i]+"'] \n },";
}

/* service.ts */
@Injectable()
export class AppMenuService {

    user : User = new User();

    constructor( private http: HttpService, private cacheservice: CacheService ) { }

    getMenusForUser() {
        debugger;
        this.user.userName = '123';
        this.user.passWord = '123';
        return this.http.post( 'getMenuItems', this.user ).toPromise()
            .then( response => {
                return <any[]>response['_body'];
            } );

    }

}
```

I want to append values to 'buffer' after getting response from getMenusForuser() method. but values are appended to the buffer before response has arrived to the component.ts